# Creación de un full tree diagram con las siguientes oraciones

Tags: diagrama-er

1. My neighbor tends to be the worst cook in the house.
2. Carlos bought a bag of chips for dinner.
3. Plenty of people have become secretive of their personal lives.
4. This is the moment where you finish the task happily.
5. Peace is a big concept not everyone can understand completely

En este caso, como quedarían estas oraciones en un full tree diagram

Debo hacer una tarea de full tree diagrams y quiero saber si alguien puede hacer las oraciones que pedi para poder revisarlas con las mias.

Y es que no puedo pegarla acá porque se me desordena cuando la pego, pero si alguien seria tan amable de ayudarme y poner los acrónimos que usaron seria un exito para yo poder guiarme

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Recuerda el [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask].